# Mongodb project only keys in an object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to return only the values in an array. I managed to solve this a few months ago on a different project but I have forgotten how.

Here is my current query and the result.

```
  database.find({todo: {$exists: true}},{projection:{_id: 0}}).toArray((error,data) => {
    console.log(data);
    res.json(data);
  });

[
  {
    todo: {
      id: '30a508fbfb8a51d2784920c2d6b7468c',
      text: 'testing',
      completed: false
    }
  },
  {
    todo: {
      id: 'dedf6f6a850f7fef02566de027e74416',
      text: 'testing',
      completed: false
    }
  }
]
```

I would like it to return only the values in the Todo array as seen below. What do I need to add in the projection field to make this happen?

```
[
  {
      id: '30a508fbfb8a51d2784920c2d6b7468c',
      text: 'testing',
      completed: false
  },
  {
      id: 'dedf6f6a850f7fef02566de027e74416',
      text: 'testing',
      completed: false
  }
]
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Turns out I was using the wrong function.

If there is anyone looking for this solution you want to use distinct and not projections.

```
  database.distinct('todo', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

This resulted in the following below which is what I was needing.

```
[
  {
    id: '30a508fbfb8a51d2784920c2d6b7468c',
    text: 'testing',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 'dedf6f6a850f7fef02566de027e74416',
    text: 'testing',
    completed: false
  }
]
```

Thanks,